# Pandas two rows have the same index, how to change them

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, append

python newbie here. 
I need to add a row from Provider 2 to Provider 1, do some calculations, save the results and drop that last row. Again, add another row from Provider 2 to Provider 1 and so forth. I'm building a loop for the purpose and I have the logic down for appending. My problem is that both provider 1 and provider 2 dataframes have indices starting from 0. So once the append statement below executes, my provider1 has two rows with index 0. How can I reindex? I looked into pandas df.reindex but that didn't help. I want to reindex so I can drop the last row in provider1 (so it's the original dataframe again). Any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

```
Provider1=Provider1.append(Provider2[:0])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True` after appending:

```
Provider1 = Provider1.reset_index(drop=True)
Provider2 = Provider2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3] }, index=[0,1,0])
print (df)
   a
0  1
1  2
0  3

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass ignore_index=True to append() to avoid this:

```
Provider1=Provider1.append(Provider2[:0], ignore_index=True)
```